# How to write file into directory as its created?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a file in a directory, right after the directory is created. I'm not sure where i'm going wrong. I think it could be because the code is executing fast enough that it doesnt realize that a directory is created? But then I should be getting errors, here is what I have so far:

```
    var userFolder = "/api/forums/users/"+user.name
            try{
                fs.accessSync(userFolder)
            }catch(e){
                if(!fs.existsSync(userFolder)){
                    var userdirectory = "/Server/yeee/server/api/forums/users/"+user.name

                    fs.mkdirSync(userdirectory) <----- this makes directory with user.name

                    fs.access(userdirectory,function(){ <---- Me trying to access the directory that was just created

                        fs.writeFileSync(userdirectory+"test","file") <---- assuming it succeeds, create file in that directory. 
                    })
                }
            }
```

I added comments in the code just to try and explain what I was trying to do. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: +"test" should be +"/test" but the proper way is path.join as stated below. Also it's a bit frightening how you mix sync and async ;) you should go all async and use fs-extra to get promises

Comment: @naholyr Thanks man, "/test" fixed it, i swear it can be the most simple things lol

Comment: Well, it fixes your code but it's still not ideal and I would highly recommend giving answer below a shot

Answer (score 1):

Always use `path.join()` or `path.resolve()` instead of concatenating with '/' or '\' else you will run into cross-platform issues (linux vs windows)
eg.

```
const path = require('path');
const userFolder = path.join('api', 'forums', 'users', user.name);
```

You must provide full path to directory. You can use `__dirname` node global variable to get current working directory eg.:

```
path.join(__dirname, users);
```

I think this cause your problem.

Comment: `__dirname` is not necessarily the same as current working directory (which is obtained with `process.cwd()`).  `__dirname` is where the current module was loaded from.  The two are not necessarily the same and will almost never be the same for dependent modules which are loaded from sub-directories.